# Collect open registry key handles with kernel rundown ETW provider

Tags: windows, winapi, etw

Recently I figured out there are ETW rundown providers that basically allows for enumerating system resources for the purpose of filling the gaps for events that might lack full trace context. For example, Process Hacker [uses](https://github.com/processhacker/processhacker/blob/1f2b747edcc682b132945cb3e33f8ee0882e00f9/plugins/ExtendedTools/etwmon.c#L478) kernel rundown logger to enumerate all open file objects that other kernel events correlate with in order to get the full file name that's involved in I/O operation. I would like to know if rundown kernel provider is also able to collect other resources (apart from process, threads, images), such as registry keys or system handles?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the [`TdhEnumerateProviderFieldInformation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/tdh/nf-tdh-tdhenumerateproviderfieldinformation) with `EventKeywordInformation` to retrieve the keyword. And there is also an example on the document.